# Troubleshooting SQL Server connection string for LocalDB

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, connection-string

I am working on a C# Windows Forms application, and I'm trying to connect to my local database, which is an attached file.

When I run my project startup the program continues to run without the windows form displaying, and no errors were shown.

After referencing multiple sources, I am still unable to work out a connection string.

Current connection string:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)/MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:/USERS/RUIHAO.LIM/DOCUMENTS/VISUAL STUDIO 2015/PROJECTS/HASH TESTING/HASH TESTING/TESTDB.MDF;Database=TestDB;Trusted_Connection=Yes;");
```

Details of my environment:

- Name: TestDBConnectionString
- Database: `C:\USERS\RUIHAO.LIM\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2015\PROJECTS\HASH TESTING\HASH TESTING\TESTDB.MDF`
- Server: `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB`
- User: `USER\ruihao.lim`

My code snippet:

```
namespace Hash_Testing
{
    public partial class CreateUser : Form
    {
        public CreateUser()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CreateUser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)/MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:/USERS/RUIHAO.LIM/DOCUMENTS/VISUAL STUDIO 2015/PROJECTS/HASH TESTING/HASH TESTING/TESTDB.MDF;Database=TestDB;Trusted_Connection=Yes;");

            con.Open();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB
```

or

```
Data Source=.\MSSQLLocalDB
```